# How to Choose and adopt information security model

Tags: risk-management

I would like to ask about how can someone adopt certain security model in the organizations what are the criteria that controls how I can pick the best security model for my organization

For example I have set up an security services (pentest- vulnerability assessment- secures network desing) and security training org. I want to adopt on the Ifo. Sec. mngt. model but I don't know what should I look for when choosing the proper model.

Thanks

Comment: I think this a very broad topic and I would recommend some professional information security and assurance training to begin with.

Comment: Is your questionmark key broken?

Comment: I got the answer for my question and I accepted it.....isn't that enough guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you have a look at the ISO27000 series - these documents act as a framework for information security.

Comment: While I believe your post does answer the question directly, I would suggest that you may do the following to improve it:
1. Provide reference URLs.
2. Provide a background of the ISO 27000 series.
3. Generally it is recommended to offer more than one option as a solution, therefore suggesting stadards apart from the ISO 27' would be good.

Comment: I had doubt about the ISO 27K series whether is it considered as a security model or not..but seems it's true that ISO 27K is also a security model..coz I read the CW and the BS 7799 and others but I felt lost..when I read the ISo 27K I felt what it says is digestible..thus I will just go for the ISOK series..thanks a bunch dude @KingJohnno

Comment: @RohanDurve-Decode141 Google ISO 27K series and you will got a website describing all the series it helps me a lot buddy